# How to send custom http response code back from spring cloud functions in gcp?

Tags: kotlin, google-cloud-platform, spring-cloud-function

We are using the new gcp cloud functions using Java / Kotlin.

As in the current reference implementations, we are returning **org.springframework.messaging.support.GenericMessage** objects.

So our code looks like this (Kotlin):

```
   fun generatePdfInBase64(message: Message<Map<String, Any>>): Message<*> {
        val document = process(message)
        val encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(document.document)
        return GenericMessage(encoded)
    }
```

We were not able to find any way to include a custom http response code to our message, e.g. 201 or something. The function only responds 200 in case of no exception or 500.

Does someone know of a way to do this?

Best wishes

Andy

Answer (score 0):

As it is mentioned at the official [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/http), the HttpResponse class has a method called [setStatusCode](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.cloud.functions/functions-framework-api/latest/com/google/cloud/functions/HttpResponse.html#setStatusCode(int,java.lang.String)) where you are able to set the number of the status as your convenience

For example:

```
 switch (request.getMethod()) {
      case "GET":
        response.setStatusCode(HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK);
        writer.write("Hello world!");
        break;
```

On the other hand the [constructor](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/messaging/support/GenericMessage.html) of the GenericMessage receives as parameter a payload, therefore I think you can create a string with a json format and use the constructor for create your GenericMessage instance with the status response you need.

If you want to know more about the statuds codes take a look at this [document](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xhtml).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. We did not find any way to insert a status code into the constructur / the headers of GenericMessage though.